# Chosen Multiple HTML, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get this.

http://tinypic.com/r/m7c2ac/8

Like chosen Multiple functionality but it can let me typed something more. I just want to know if there is some framework that do it or some way different.

Comment: Take a look at [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

Comment: thanks you, but demo's ui-select doesn't work as i expected. Thanks!